# is there anything wrong with "from my perspective"

Tags: idioms

Is the expression "from my perspective" good English? I was always under the impression that "perspective" refers to what someone else can see (i.e. a third person), and that if you wanted to refer to what you yourself can see you should say "in my view". What do you think?

Comment: Sounds like you need to look up the word *perspective*

Answer (score 1):

I guess it can work well, from my perspective:

**Perspective:**
 a way of regarding situations, facts, etc, and judging their relative importance.

- my view
- my point of view
- my viewpoint

are all possible alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely fine, and entirely natural English (to my native British ears). It can mean roughly the same as 'in my view', though there are cases where 'perspective' might sound better, eg:

- from my perspective, as a student with mounting debt...

In this case the position of the speaker clearly informs the opinion, so it would be odd to say 'view' instead.

Answer (score 1):

> I was always under the impression that "perspective" refers to what someone else can see (i.e. a third person),

This is what dictionaries are for. There are always senses and meanings that one isn't aware of, so even if you weren't mistaken (though you were) you couldn't be sure there wasn't another meaning without checking at least one good dictionary.

> and that if you wanted to refer to what you yourself can see you should say "in my view".

They're pretty much synonymous.

> What do you think?

It's valid but overused and often misused. It's commonly used as a weasel word when the opinion stated doesn't actually relate to their perspective at all, but is simply their opinion. The same is true of "in my view".

If though you actually do have a genuinely different perspective rather than merely a different opinion, then it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

first, visit online dictionaries and see its usage. "from my perspective" is just fine. if you say "it looked good from my perspective" and "it looked good from my point of view", they are the same. your perspective is just how you look at things.

just like everyone perceives things differently, everyone has different perspectives.

how you recognize, discern, distinguish and grasp things, along with your actions, is related to your perspective or view of the situation at hand.